# Get element of an array by its contents

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm sorry for weird wording.  I don't know what you call this.  I have this array:

```
[#<Item:0x007faeea066508 @name="Backpack", @exam="Not much here... just a backpack">]
```

This is an inventory array.  The user will type something like "examine backpack" and it will return the @exam of of the element.  How would you get that element only knowing @name?  Thanks!

Comment: If the reader is puzzled by this array, it contains a single element: an instance of the class `Item`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you have:

```
class Item
  # accessors for @name and @exam possibly defined here
  def initialize(name, exam)
    @name = name
    @exam = exam
  end
  # methods possibly defined here
end

item = Item.new("Backpack", "Just a backpack")
  #=> #<Item:0x0000010201dda0 @name="Backpack", @exam="Just a backpack">
```

So you have an array `a` with one element, an instance of class `Item` with the instance variables `@name` and `@exam` having the values "Backpack" and "Just a backpack", respectively:

```
a = [item]
  #=> [#<Item:0x0000010201dda0 @name="Backpack", @exam="Just a backpack">]
```

You can use [Object#instance_variable_get](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get) to retrieve the values of the instance variables `@name` and `@exam`, which I will store in local variables `name` and `exam`:

```
name = a.first.instance_variable_get(:@name) #=> "Backpack" 
exam = a.first.instance_variable_get(:@exam) #=> "Just a backpack"
```

Now that you have the values of those variables, you can do whatever you like with them.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to select using a block (assuming your Item class responds to .name and .exam:

```
items = [#<Item:0x007faeea066508 @name="Backpack", @exam="Not much here... just a backpack">]
item = items.select {|i| i.name =~ /backpack/i }
puts item.exam
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code:

```
articles = ArticleType.all
```

My result:

```
[#<ArticleType id: 1, name: "News", slug: "news">, #<ArticleType id: 2, name: "Articles", slug: "articles">]
```

To get the name's value of the first element:

```
articles[0].name
=> "News"
```

To get the name's values of your array:

```
ArticleType.all.map(&:name)
```

To get the elements that contains 'N':

```
ArticleType.all.map { |x| puts x.name if x.name.include?('N') }
=> News
```

I hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as following:--

```
user_typed_string =  "examine backpack" 

items = [#<Item:0x007faeea066508 @name="Backpack", @exam="Not much here... just a backpack">]

item = items.select {|i| user_typed_string.include?(i.name) }.last

exam = item.exam unless item.nil?
```